# Area in the spherical coordinate system

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I need to configure a constant infinitesimal area (constant magnitude) on the surface of a sphere. But the elemental area $dA=r^2\sin \theta d\theta \,d\phi$ which depends on $\theta$.

Does it mean, I can't take the same area at different $\theta$ positions ?

Comment: Right. This should make sense, if you visualize what a small rectangular patch of the surface looks like under the $\theta, \phi$ parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

Curious question, I wonder if the observation that $dA=r^2 \sin \theta d\theta d\phi = -r^2 d(\cos\theta) d\phi$ is at all helpful to your quest? In other words, let $u = \cos \theta$ and observe $dA = -r^2 du d\phi$. Then the scale factor $r^2$ is invariant on the sphere and perhaps this would solve your problem? The modified, quasi-spherical coordinate system this implicits is:
$$ x = r\sin( \cos^{-1}(u))\cos \phi, \ \ \ y=r\sin( \cos^{-1}(u))\sin \phi, \ \ \ z = ru $$
of course you could write the composite of sin and the inverse cosine as algebraic functions using the standard identities, but I leave it as this for now.

Comment: This is only helpful if you interpret $du\,d\theta$ as the element of area of a zone of a sphere and know that that is invariant of the latitude on the sphere. Pretty much begging the question.

Comment: @TedShifrin what should my goal be in improving the answer? Honestly, I'm not sure I entirely understand the rules of the same which we are playing here. My rudimentary thinking was just that he wished for $dA$ in terms of parameters differentials with no point-dependent scale factor. It's more than this?